# Difference between getLine and readLn

Tags: haskell, io

I get no runtime errors when I run the following code:

```
printReverse :: IO ()
printReverse = do
    line <- getLine
    when (not $ null line) $
            do putStrLn $ reverse line
               printReverse
    return ()
```

But when I run the same code except that I replaced `getLine` with `readLn :: IO String`, I get a parse error.

**Code:**

```
printReverse :: IO ()
printReverse = do
    line <- readLn :: IO String
    when (not $ null line) $
            do putStrLn $ reverse line
               printReverse
    return ()
```

**Error:**

```
*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)
```

What's the difference here between getLine and readLn?

Comment: Apparently what you're reading is not a string representation of a string? (hint: look at the type of `readLn`) (hint2: why do you have to specify the specific type?)

Comment: @JanDvorak I've tried both code samples with the same input "derp" without the quotation marks.

Comment: Try both with the quotes and observe the difference. Also, have you read the documentation yet?

Comment: @JanDvorak The quotes stay using the first code sample. I don't get a parse error anymore when I use quotes with the second code sample but the quotes are removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the types.

```
readLn :: Read a => IO a
```

and

```
getLine :: IO String
```

`readLn` parses the input according to the 'Read' format of the result type. This is the same format as `show`.

So you're attempting to `read` a Haskell String value, in `show` format from input, which is confusing, unless the string is already in double-qyoted haskell format.

Comment: " This is the same format as show." -- usually and for all built-in types, but there's no actual requirement  for that to be the case.

Comment: Jan right but I want to point out that it's not just a guideline, it's a law. So I'll nitpick and say that it's not just usually; It is! And if it's not then there is an error with the instance definition.